# How to design a template to satisfy either std::queue or std::priority_queue?

Tags: templates, c++17

I want to design a template like

```
template<typename T, typename QueueType = std::queue<std::shared_ptr<T>>>
class ThreadSafeQueue {};
template<typename T>
auto cmp = [](const T& d1, const T& d2) { return d1 > d2; };
template<typename T>
using ThreadSafePriorityQueue = ThreadSafeQueue<T,
    std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<T>,
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>>,
    decltype(cmp<std::shared_ptr<T>>)>>;
```

And call it simply like

```
struct S {
    bool operator>(const S& other) const {
        return false;
    }
};

ThreadSafeQueue<S> q;
ThreadSafePriorityQueue<S> q1;
```

But it could not compile under c++17 which returns `error C2280`, but seems well under c++20.
Why is that?
And how to modify it if I insist using c++17?

Comment: C++20 allowed for default construction of objects of a lambda's type

Comment: hmm, can't reproduce on anythign else. It appears that in some versions of MSVC v19 non-capturing lambda behaves like capturing under some circumstances

Comment: Which exact version of MSVC?

Comment: Your `cmp` seems to be equivalent to `std::greater<>`, so might as well just use that and avoid the funny lambda business.

Comment: Note that `operator>` for `std::shared_ptr` compares underlying raw pointers, not the objects they point to. `cmp<std::shared_ptr<S>>` will not call `S::operator>`